# Manipular objeto em node via retorno do banco

Tags: javascript, mysql, express.js

Estou montando um objeto conforme os valores retornados pelo banco de dados.
Atualmente, estou fazendo desta forma:

```
let games;

execSQLQuery(query, form_values)
        .then(dbResponse => {
            if (dbResponse != "") {
                for(let i = 0; i < dbResponse.length; i++){
                    games =[{
                        name: dbResponse[i].nome_sg,
                        evaluation: dbResponse[i].heuristic_status,
                        cod_sg: dbResponse[i].cod_sg
                    }];
                }
```

Acontece que, caso o retorno seja composto por mais de um grupo de valores, o meu objeto só recebe o valor do último.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que você está alterando o valor de `games` após cada iteração. Ao invés de **alterar** todo o array, você deve **adicionar** um novo objeto após cada iteração.

Suponha o código abaixo (o que você faz atualmente):

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let newItems = []

for (const item of items) {
  const toAdd = item * 2
  console.log('Alterando para', toAdd)
  
  // Note abaixo que, por estarmos utilizando o operador de atribuição (`=`), substituimos,
  // a cada iteração, o valor de `newItems`. Isso não é o que queremos.
  newItems = [toAdd]
}

console.log(newItems)
```

Logo, para resolver isso, precisamos adicionar o item de cada iteração ao array. Para isso, vamos usar o método [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```js
const items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
const newItems = []

for (const item of items) {
  const toAdd = item * 2
  console.log('Adicionando', toAdd)
  
  // Note abaixo que, ao invés de substituirmos todo o array `newItems` após
  // cada iteração, estamos adicionando o valor do loop atual ao array existente.
  // Para isso, estamos utilizando o `Array.prototype.push`:
  newItems.push(toAdd)
}

console.log(newItems)
```

Logo, no seu exemplo, você precisa de fazer o seguinte:

```
// Precisamos inicializar `games` como um `array` vazio:
const games = []

execSQLQuery(query, form_values).then((dbResponse) => {
  if (dbResponse != '') {
    for (let i = 0; i < dbResponse.length; i++) {
      // Abaixo estamos utilizando o método `push` para adicionar o objeto
      // da iteração atual ao array `games`:
      games.push({
        name: dbResponse[i].nome_sg,
        evaluation: dbResponse[i].heuristic_status,
        cod_sg: dbResponse[i].cod_sg
      })
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: perfeito, luiz, muito obrigado! sua explicação foi sensacional